# @XmlSeeAlso Inheritance trouble

Tags: java, web-services

If I Have

```
@XmlSeeAlso{B,C,D} 
abstract class A{
}
```

and

```
@XmlSeeAlso{X,Y}
abstract  class D extends A{
}
```

and

```
class X extends D{}, class Y extends D{}
```

what will happen if I use

webservice method

```
 @WebMethod
 @WebResult
   read(@WebParam A a)
```

and pass there X ?

Comment: How can you pass X? That's a class. read() accepts an argument of type A.

Comment: And, just a little note besides that - it's "@XmlSeeAlso({B.class, C.class, D.class})" (notice the parentheses). Also, read() method does not have a return type.